# How to disable split desktop window dragging?

Tags: kde, 23.04

Just updated to Kubuntu 23.04 and noticed this: when I have 2 windows split on the desktop, one on the left-half and other on the right-half - dragging the window size in the middle drags both windows.

How can I turn this behavior off permanently?

As well - as soon as I drag this middle part once, all other windows are aligning to this new percentage instead of 50/50 when pressing `meta+left`/`meta+right`, and I could not find a way to restore the 50/50.